# Creating a user-controllable RxSwift Observer

Tags: swift, system.reactive, frp, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement user-driven refreshing in my Rx based networking code, and my current design is as follows:

1. Create a sink that has `Void` values passed into it every time the user initiates a refresh action
2. `flatMap` the latest `.Next` event on that sink's `Observable` into a new network call
3. Transform the network response into a new view model and pass that back into the view controller

The part I'm getting hung up on is how to create a sink for those events to go down. My current code is as follows:

```
func contactListModel() -> Observable<ContactListViewModel<Contact>> {
    // Create a sink for refresh events
    var refreshSink: AnyObserver<Void> = AnyObserver { event in }
    let refreshObservable = Observable<Void>.create { observer in
        refreshSink = observer
        return NopDisposable.instance
    }

    // Define action handlers
    let searchClosure = { (query: String?) in
        self.contactsSearchTerm.value = query
    }
    let refreshClosure = refreshSink.onNext

    // TODO: [RP] Make contact list view controller handle a nil view model to remove the need for this code
    let initialViewModel = ContactListViewModel<Contact>(contacts: [], searchClosure: searchClosure, refreshClosure: refreshClosure)

    // Perform an initial refresh
    defer {
        refreshSink.onNext()
    }

    // Set up subscription to push a new view model each refresh
    return refreshObservable
        .flatMapLatest {
            return self.networking.request(.ListContacts)
        }
        .mapToObject(ListContactsResponse)
        .map { response in
            return ContactListViewModel(contacts: response.contacts, searchClosure: searchClosure, refreshClosure: refreshClosure)
        }
        .startWith(initialViewModel)
}
```

Now it's obvious why my code to create an event sink doesn't work here. The block being passed into `refreshObservable`'s `create` method is only called once the observer is subscribed to, so the `refreshSink` won't be reassigned until then. Furthermore, if this observable is subscribed to more than once, the `refreshSink` variable will be reassigned.

So my question is this: *how do I create an `Observable` that I can manually push events down? Or alternatively, is there a better design I could be using here?*

I know ReactiveCocoa has the `pipe` static method on `Signal` that will do something like what I'm looking for, but I've found no equivalent in the Rx API.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your case fully, but have you looked at `PublishSubject`?